# format of the date format (from SQL to PHP

Tags: php, sql, date

Can I change format of the format of the date? I'm using it in queries and in php date formatting.

I have formats like that:

```
%Y-%m-%d %H:00
%Y-%m-%d
```

and I'm converting it to

```
Y-m-d H:00
Y-m-d
```

for now I can just do

```
str_replace('%', '', $format)
```

but is there more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: where is your `sql` query ?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(updated, '%Y-%m-%d') as day FROM TABLE

- how does it help?

Comment: add your `php` code with the query you executed.
like : `$query = "some query" ; $db->execute($query); .... while or foreach` loop used in php code please add complete code which is needed to sort out your problem.

Comment: \DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(updated, $this->sqlFormat) as day FROM TABLE") I use it like this, and it works, but I have to set slqFormat manually for every date format i use.

Comment: if you want to show multiple date display format you can use php `date()` function with `strtotime()` with any kind formatted date

Comment: but I want to use the same Y-m-d H:00, Y-m-d or Y-m-d H:i:s in mysql